# I do not understand why my column in my dataset is NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to create a fare band (1/2/3) through this loop but it does not seem to be working

```
traindf['FareBand'] = np.nan

for index, row in traindf.iterrows():
    if row['Fare'] <= 13.675550:
        row['FareBand'] = 1
    elif row['Fare'] <= 20.662183 and row['Fare'] > 13.675550:
        row['FareBand'] = 2
    else:
        row['FareBand'] = 3
```

Running .head() will show that all my rows under the column fareband are NaN

```
traindf.head(20)

Output:
       0    NaN
       1    NaN
       2    NaN
       3    NaN
       ...
       12   NaN
       13   NaN
       14   NaN
       15   NaN
       16   NaN
       17   NaN
       18   NaN
       19   NaN
       Name: FareBand, dtype: float64
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: see the whole dataset changes might be down somewhere... also please execute the code on a small data like 10 rows then update here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
traindf = pd.DataFrame({'Fare':[10,15,3,30]})

m1 = traindf['Fare'] <= 13.675550
m2 = (traindf['Fare'] <= 20.662183) & (traindf['Fare'] > 13.675550)

traindf['FareBand'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1,2], 3)
print (traindf)
   Fare  FareBand
0    10         1
1    15         2
2     3         1
3    30         3
```

Your solution is possible change for select values by index, but dont use it, because slow:

```
for index, row in traindf.iterrows():
    if traindf.loc[index, 'Fare'] <= 13.675550:
        traindf.loc[index, 'FareBand'] = 1
    elif row['Fare'] <= 20.662183 and traindf.loc[index, 'Fare'] > 13.675550:
        traindf.loc[index, 'FareBand'] = 2
    else:
        traindf.loc[index, 'FareBand'] = 3

print (traindf)
   Fare  FareBand
0    10       1.0
1    15       2.0
2     3       1.0
3    30       3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in three steps without the loop:

```
traindf['FareBand'] = 3
traindf.loc[traindf['Fare'].between(13.675550, 20.662183), 'FareBand'] = 2
traindf.loc[traindf['Fare'].le(13.675550), 'FareBand'] = 1
```

Comment: be carefull with between, because `<=` and `>` is not possible set.

Comment: what does .le do @Alex

Comment: less than or equal to, see [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.le.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the method you described, applying changes inside of a loop, all you need to do is set the value of the dataframe's row at the specific index position:

```
for index, row in traindf.iterrows():
    if row['Fare'] <= 13.675550:
        row['FareBand'] = 1
    elif row['Fare'] <= 20.662183 and row['Fare'] > 13.675550:
        row['FareBand'] = 2
    else:
        row['FareBand'] = 3
    traindf.loc[index] = row
```